# What is org.netbeans.modules.options.editor.spi.PreferencesCustomizer in the NetBeans Platform?

Tags: java, netbeans-platform

I am porting an old application based on the NetBeans Platform 8.2 to the new NetBeans Platform 11.2 version. This application contains references to the following classes:

```
org.netbeans.modules.options.editor.spi.PreferencesCustomizer
org.netbeans.modules.options.editor.spi.PreviewProvider
```

I can't find them via Googling, searching through Maven Central, or asking on the Apache NetBeans mailing list.

Does anyone know what these are, and where to find them? Maven coordinates would be ideal, but just a download of their JAR or source code would be fine, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two interfaces can be found in this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.netbeans.modules</groupId>
    <artifactId>org-netbeans-modules-options-editor</artifactId>
    <version>RELEASE112</version>
</dependency>
```

And their location within the GIT repository (containing quite extensive documentation):

[PreferencesCustomizer](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/blob/0f2e98d513deaedccef831ee9cfc08d09f3650b6/ide/options.editor/src/org/netbeans/modules/options/editor/spi/PreferencesCustomizer.java)

[PreviewProvider](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/blob/0f2e98d513deaedccef831ee9cfc08d09f3650b6/ide/options.editor/src/org/netbeans/modules/options/editor/spi/PreviewProvider.java)